# Inaccessible USB Mass Storage Device (Bricked Garmin device)

Tags: usb, storage, firmware

I've got a running GPS watch (Garmin Forerunner 210, fwiw) which recently got bricked during a firmware update. Let's assume for point of discussion that an rma is not possible, so I'd really like to get it fixed. It's supposed to connect as a USB mass storage device, and if I can succeed with that I have the firmware that needs to be put on the device. The problem is that it's not connecting as a USB mass storage device.

I'm running Ubuntu, and it's recognizing it to some extent... the output of lsusb has it there:

```
Bus 006 Device 099: ID 091e:0003 Garmin International GPS (various models)
```

Also output of `dmesg` shows this:

```
[45192.496141] usb 6-2: new full-speed USB device number 99 using uhci_hcd
[45192.646217] usb 6-2: New USB device found, idVendor=091e, idProduct=0003
[45192.646226] usb 6-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

So long story short, the question is are there any possible solutions to somehow get the USB mass storage part of the device working again - or even write the bytes that I need to write directly via `dd` or some other method?